# ADO.NET requesting existing connection string

Tags: ado.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

I created an ADO.NET object in my WCF service project, but when I try to connect in it I get this error:

> No connection string named 'FileEntities' could be found in the
>   application config file.

Here is my code:

> ```
>     public File GetFile()
>     {
>         using (FileEntities ctx = new FileEntities())
>         {
>             File aFile = (from f in ctx.Files
>                           where f.ID == 5
>                           select f).FirstOrDefault();       // No connection string named 'FileEntities' could be found in the
> ```
>
> application config file.
>                   return aFile;
>               }
>           }

Here is the App.Config for my service project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FileEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HOOVERS-PC;initial catalog=Interview_MicahHoover;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I have tried removing the "name=" prefix in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the problem was my service project just builds a library. The project that uses the library doesn't have the connection string in it. I added the connection string to that project and it (mostly) works.

Keeping things like this straight is a reason to not break things up into a lot of projects, but the WCF O'Reilly book recommends it.